# Как заменить текст в файле php

Tags: php

Есть PHP-файл, который скачивает csv-файл по ссылке.
Он скачивает файл по указанной ссылке и переименовывает его под указанное в коде значение.

Как дополнить данный код так, чтобы он открыл скачанный файл, и заменил по всему файлу одно значение на другое?

```html
<?php


// Каталог files
$link = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/id/pub?output=csv';
$uploaddir = './';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($link);



// Копируем файл в files
if (copy($link, $uploadfile)){
    
    $old = "pub?output=csv";
    $new = "google_sheets.csv";
    rename($old , $new);

     echo "Файл успешно загружен на сервер";
}

?>
```

Comment: Зачем вы вообще писали про то, что вы что-то скачиваете? «Есть файл, формат такой-то, как поменять вот это на это?»

Comment: Сто тысяч ответов в гугеле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
// Каталог files
$link = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/id/pub?output=csv';
$uploaddir = './';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($link);

// Копируем файл в files
if (copy($link, $uploadfile)){
    
    $old = "./pub?output=csv";
    $new = "./google_sheets.csv";
    rename($old , $new);

    echo "Файл успешно загружен на сервер";
}
```